# Can we load an external bundle from an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, bundle

Is it possible to download and use a bundle from an iOS app?

I want to know how I would download and use files that aren't available at design time. I tried creating a bundle type project and downloading it to a specific location but it won't open...

```
var bundle = Bundle(path: "/Library/Caches/NewAssets.bundle")
```

This code always results in nil bundle. The path is hard coded here just for testing the load. I've tried the full path as well as the path you see here. The FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath:) returns true (using the full path). I've been looking through as many resources as I can find but they all eventually lead to dropping the bundle in your project, which I can't do because they're not available at design time.
I think I might be chasing a ghost because I can't find anything that says bundles work with iOS. I can load my main bundle, and the bundle from a framework but not the external one. If that's the case then how would we download resources at runtime? (We already have a solution for downloading the assets from iCloud but the client wants to see if this is faster and can provide better UX)

TIA,
Mike

Comment: What kind of assets/files are we talking about? Apple won't allow downloading executable code. If it's images and such then you should be able to download them into your Documents folder or tmp folder.

Comment: Just JSON and images. There's also the Info.plist that's a standard part of all bundles. I can download the file and move it from the temporary location to the shared folder which is the /Library/Caches/ folder that's relative to the app and shared. I've already used this location for files in the previous version. FileManager says it's there but I can't create a bundle from the path.

Comment: Why do you think you need a bundle?

Comment: Part of the content is delivered in the application bundle. Since I already have a routine that works with a bundle I thought the best way to keep it DRY was to just open a different bundle and use the existing code to parse the JSON and provide the URLs to resources within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out there were two problems. Inside the bundle was a 'Thumbs.db' which the finder shows as an exec file. That might have been interpreted as code to prevent the bundle from loading. The other problem was that the whole bundle wasn't downloading. I wrapped the bundle in a zip, then (after downloading) unzipped the file where it's supposed to live and fed that into the bundle code I had and everything's fine.

Mike